# Is It Possible To Edit OpenCL Kernels On The GPU?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu, hpc

I am looking to edit (or generate new) OpenCL kernels on the GPU from an executing kernel.

Right now, the only way I can see of doing this is to create a buffer full of numbers representing code on the device, send that buffer to an array on the host, generate/compile a new kernel on the host, and enqueue the new kernel back to the device.

Is there any way to avoid a round trip to the host, and just edit kernels on the device?

Can a kernel access the registers in any way?

Comment: I don't have time to write a long answer but the short answer is: **no**. You cannot edit kernels on the GPU, you cannot schedule kernels to run from the GPU, and you cannot modify the code of a kernel while it is running. GPU's have a completely different architecture than your CPU, do not have any form of operating system, and are entirely controlled by the host driver. What you are asking for cannot be done, and the fact that you need it suggests there may be a design flaw in your project. What are you trying to do? Perhaps knowing more would help people point out alternative approaches.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!  You are right to say that most programs looking for this feature might have a design flaw, but this program is different.  The device > host > device round-trip will be adequate.  I just had to make sure there was no other way. Thanks!

Comment: The round trip will be the least of the time spent; the majority of time will be in the compiler. I'm curious what kind of problem you are solving, this sounds pretty interesting.

Comment: I thought you might like to know, I just looked at the upcoming OpenCL 2.0 spec and apparently (much to my surprise) there is some limited capability to enqueue kernels on the device side without host interaction. Check out the OpenCL 2.0 C specification, section 6.13.17 (Enqueuing Kernels) at http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/. I imagine this is only syntactic, though, and will still just enqueue the kernel host-side to be compiled (if necessary) and then executed, rather than immediately dispatched device-side, but I have not tried it. Worth a look, in any case (there is a short snippet).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much for finding that feature!  Having even a little control over the queue from inside the currently executing kernel will be enormously helpful.

Comment: @benshope Some more info, it turns out it's more than just syntactic sugar: from the [November 18 press release](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-finalizes-opencl-2.0-specification-for-heterogeneous-computing): "Device kernels can enqueue kernels to the same device **with no host interaction**, enabling flexible work scheduling paradigms and avoiding the need to transfer execution control and data between the device and host, often significantly offloading host processor bottlenecks." So once 2.0 implementations become available, you should be able to achieve your goal elegantly.